# PowerShell Invalid filter clause

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to execute and get the result using the below command:

```
$usertype = 'member'
Get-MgUser -All:$true -Filter 'UserType -eq "$usertype" -and OnPremisesSyncEnabled -eq "$true" and usagelocation -like "*"'| 
                Select-Object UserPrincipalName, ID, DisplayName, CreatedDateTime, SignInActivity, OnPremisesSyncEnabled, Usagelocation
```

But it always failed with the error below:

```
Get-MgUser : Invalid filter clause
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-MgUser -All:$true -Filter 'UserType -eq "$usertype" -and OnPremis ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: ({ ConsistencyLe...ndProperty =  }:<>f__AnonymousType59`9) [Get-MgUser_List], RestException`1
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadRequest,Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Cmdlets.GetMgUser_List
```

Comment: `$usertype` and `$true` will not be interpolated (if that's what you're expecting), as the entire filter value is inside single quotes.  Try using double quotes instead.  Also, one of the 'and' operators seems to be missing a dash.

Comment: Ok, so how does it looks like when updated ?
because the issue remain the same after I change the double to single quote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Filter is send to the graphAPI - you can't use the operators (e.g. -eq) as on PowerShell, the syntax is different see:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/filter-query-parameter

Also there are limitations which attributes you can use in queries, which combination of attributes and also which operators for which attributes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http

In principle if you define a filter you have to enclose the whole filter in double quotes and the strings within the filter in single quotes, so your filter would have to look like this:

```
"UserType eq '$usertype' and OnPremisesSyncEnabled eq true and usagelocation like '*'"
```

But this will also not work, because wildcards are not supported and also there is no operator 'like'. Also note if a string contains a single quote you have to double it to escape. URL encoding is done by the cmdlet but not escaping....

Check the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/users?view=graph-rest-1.0

Also note that you often have to use the beta API to do common stuff, e.g. to query the lastSignInDate for a user. You can switch to the beta API:

```
select-mgprofile -name beta
```

But back to your filter - you can only do:

```
get-mguser -all -Filter "usertype eq '$usertype' and OnPremisesSyncEnabled eq true" | ?{$_.UsageLocation}
```

Currently you can't do `UsageLocation ne 'null'` because you will get: `Unsupported property filter clause operator 'NotEqualsMatch'`. So you have to filter at shell level.

Sooner or later you will have to learn about consistencyLevel and countVariable:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/build-advanced-queries-with-count-filter-search-and-orderby/

Also note if you loop over some thousand objects or you query the auditlog you will probably face task cancelled/timeout exceptions. Those are related to the throttling "feature" of the graphAPI. There is a hard limit of 2.000 requests per second. If so take a look at json batching -> invoke-mggraphRequest...

So hope this helps, sadly the graphAPI is far away from the performance and useability which you probably know from the good old AD.

Comment: Maybe he's looking for non-null usagelocations?  The only thing I've found is `ge ' '` for non-blank.

Comment: It depends on the properties. U can also do ne null... Will add some stuff to the answer, but currently on the way home by train...

Comment: Hi @Toni, That's great, thank you for the update and the explanation, the filter is now working after your suggestion. many thanks for your assistance in this matter.